# Kalman filter (minimum-mean-squared error)

Tags: random-variables, kalman-filter

Suppose that $\Theta, Z_1, Z_2,...Z_n,$ are jointly Gaussian random vectors and that $Z_1, Z_2,..., Z_n,$ are mutually independent and have zero means. Show that minimum-mean-squared-error estimate of $%\Theta$ given $Z_1, Z_2,..., Z_n,$ is given by

\begin{align*}
\hat{\Theta} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}E[\Theta|Z]-(n-1)E[\Theta]\\
\end{align*}